# Writing large Excel sheet using SXSSF POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm writing a large Excel sheet (more than one million records) using the streaming work sheet of POI (), but I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Here is my code:

```
 public void exportExcel() {
            try {
                SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

                List<Oject> list = dao.getList();
                Cell cell = null;
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {

                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
                cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("s1");

                cell = row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue("s2");

                cell = row.createCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue("s3");

                cell = row.createCell(3);
                cell.setCellValue("s4");

                cell = row.createCell(4);
                cell.setCellValue("s5");

                cell = row.createCell(5);
                cell.setCellValue("s6");

                cell = row.createCell(6);
                cell.setCellValue("s7");

                cell = row.createCell(7);
                cell.setCellValue("s8");

                cell = row.createCell(8);
                cell.setCellValue("s9");

                cell = row.createCell(9);
                cell.setCellValue("s10");

                cell = row.createCell(10);
                cell.setCellValue("s11");

                cell = row.createCell(11);
                cell.setCellValue("s12");

                cell = row.createCell(12);
                cell.setCellValue("s13");

                cell = row.createCell(13);
                cell.setCellValue("s14");

                cell = row.createCell(14);
                cell.setCellValue("s15");

                cell = row.createCell(15);
                cell.setCellValue("s16");

                cell = row.createCell(16);
                cell.setCellValue("s17");

                cell = row.createCell(17);
                cell.setCellValue("s18");

                cell = row.createCell(18);
                cell.setCellValue("s19");

                cell = row.createCell(19);
                cell.setCellValue("s20");

                cell = row.createCell(20);
                cell.setCellValue("s21");

                cell = row.createCell(21);
                cell.setCellValue("s22");

                cell = row.createCell(22);
                cell.setCellValue("s23");

                cell = row.createCell(23);
                cell.setCellValue("s24");

                cell = row.createCell(24);
                cell.setCellValue("s25");

                cell = row.createCell(25);
                cell.setCellValue("s26");

                cell = row.createCell(26);
                cell.setCellValue("s27");

                cell = row.createCell(27);
                cell.setCellValue("s28");

                cell = row.createCell(28);
                cell.setCellValue("s29");

                cell = row.createCell(29);
                cell.setCellValue("s30");

                cell = row.createCell(30);
                cell.setCellValue("s31");

                cell = row.createCell(31);
                cell.setCellValue("s32");

                cell = row.createCell(32);
                cell.setCellValue("s33");

                cell = row.createCell(33);
                cell.setCellValue("s34");

                cell = row.createCell(34);
                cell.setCellValue("s35");

                cell = row.createCell(35);
                cell.setCellValue("s36");

                cell = row.createCell(36);
                cell.setCellValue("s37");

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);

                    cell = row.createCell(0);
                    if (list.get(i).getOne == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getOne);
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(1);
                    if (list.get(i).getTwo() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getTwo());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(2);
                    if (list.get(i).getThree() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getThree());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(3);
                    if (list.get(i).getFour() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getFour().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(4);
                    if (list.get(i).getFive() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getFive());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(5);
                    if (list.get(i).getSix() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getSix());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(6);
                    if (list.get(i).getSeven() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getSeven());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(7);
                    if (list.get(i).getEight() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getEight());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(8);
                    if (list.get(i).getNine() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getNine());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(9);
                    if (list.get(i).getTen() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getTen().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(10);
                    if (list.get(i).getD() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getD());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(11);
                    if (list.get(i).getF() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getF().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(12);
                    if (list.get(i).getV() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getV().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(13);
                    if (list.get(i).getVa() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getVa().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(14);
                    if (list.get(i).getFo() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getFo().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(15);
                    if (list.get(i).getVar() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getVar().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(16);
                    if (list.get(i).getVarm() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getVarm().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(17);
                    if (list.get(i).getFor() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getFor().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(18);
                    if (list.get(i).getVarp() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getVarp().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(19);
                    if (list.get(i).getVau() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getVau().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(20);
                    if (list.get(i).getFoi() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getFoi().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(21);
                    if (list.get(i).getVaro() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getVaro());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(22);
                    if (list.get(i).getVo() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getvo().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(23);
                    if (list.get(i).getF5() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getF5().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(24);
                    if (list.get(i).getV5() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getV5().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(25);
                    if (list.get(i).getVm5() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getVm5().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(26);
                    if (list.get(i).getDo() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getDo().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(27);
                    if (list.get(i).getDmow() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getDmow().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(28);
                    if (list.get(i).getCut() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getCut());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(29);
                    if (list.get(i).getDre() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getDre().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(30);
                    if (list.get(i).getCli() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getCli());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(31);
                    if (list.get(i).getDn() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getDn().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(32);
                    if (list.get(i).getCod() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getCod());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(33);
                    if (list.get(i).getCk() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getCk());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(34);
                    if (list.get(i).getRem() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getRem().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(35);
                    if (list.get(i).getPs() == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getPs().toString());
                    }

                    cell = row.createCell(36);
                    if (list.get(i).getTyp) == null) {
                        cell.setCellValue("");
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getTyp().toString());
                    }

                }

            }

            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext()
           externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Lim_" + new Date().toString() + ".xlsx\"");

            workbook.write(externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());
            facesContext.responseComplete();
            workbook.dispose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", null));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please I need to understand the problem as the size of the list is varying, my heap size is 512m

Comment: are you using `eclipse`.

Comment: you iterate throgh dozents of methods, you should read about "push and pop" and lifecycle of your variables. Why the heck are you accsessing all your createCell() methods statically and not with createCell(i);

Comment: Iam using netbeans, I know the number of cells so I don't need to iterate over them

Answer (score 2):

When you create a streaming workbook with `new SXSSFWorkbook();`, you implicitly specify *unlimited* row access. This is usually not what you want for writing. I'd suggest adding an integer argument to the constructor, e.g.

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
```

This should greatly reduce memory consumption. You could even use `1` as number, as long as you only write rows sequentially.

Comment: Still the same problem, any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to extract the Excel-Writing code from your JSF code and run it directly under the same memory constraints. If that works, you probably need to change either your JSF config or code, because it may well be that JSF tries to store your large worksheet in memory so it can set a size header prior to sending it.